# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TextInput'

Tags: python, kivy, password-generator

I am developing a Kivy password generator. The user is required to input a number (digit) into the app for password generate depending on how many characters are intended. Then, the app will generate a random character from the randint, finally, the output will be displayed into the output entry for a copy to the click board. Following are my code:

**password_generator.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

from random  import randint


Builder.load_file('password_generator.kv')

Window.size = (350, 600)

class MainApp(App):
    title='Password Generator'
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (255/255, 255/255, 0, 1) 
        return Mylayout()  

    def password(self):
  
        self.root.ids.output_entry = ''

        pw_length = int(self.root.ids.input_entry)
       
        my_password = ''

        for x in range(pw_length):
            my_password += chr(randint(33, 126))

        self.root.ids.output_entry = my_password

  
    def clip_board(self):
        self.root.clipboard_clear()

        self.root.clipboard_append(self.root.ids.output_entry)

    def delete(self):
        self.root.ids.input_entry = ''
        self.root.ids.output_entry = ''
    
class Mylayout(Widget):    
    pass
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**password_generator.kv**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyLayout>
              
    FloatLayout:
        
        Label:
            id: label_frame
            text: 'How Many Characters?'
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            font_size: 24

       
        TextInput:
            id: input_entry
            text: ''
            multiline: False
            font_family: 'Helvatica' 
            font_size: 24
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':4.5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            halign: "center"
            focus: True
            color: 'black'

        Button:
            text:'Generate A Strong Password'
            on_press: app.password()
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':3.8}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            font_size: 15

        TextInput:
            id: output_entry
            text: ''
            multiline: False
            font_family: 'Helvatica' 
            font_size: 24
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':3}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            halign: "center"
            focus: True
            color: 'black'
            background_color : (255/255, 255/255, 0, 1) 
            #foreground_color:  self.background_color
            color : 'black'

        Button:
            text : 'Copy To Clickboard'
            on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open(),
            on_press: app.clip_board()
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':2.5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            font_size: 15
       
        Button:
            text : "Reset"
            on_press : app.delete()
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':1.5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            font_size: 15

<MyPopup@Popup>
    # auto_dismiss: False
    auto_dismiss: True
    size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
    pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'top':0.6} 

    title: "Message Informed"

    BoxLayout 
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: "Password Copied!"
            font_size: 15
        Button: 
            text: "Close!"
            font_size: 15
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

When I click Generate Strong Password button and was required to output a random password character in the output entry, however, the following error was incurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\password_generator.py", line 53, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion        
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down    
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down     
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\password_generator.kv", line 30, in <module>
     on_press: app.password()
   File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\password_generator.py", line 24, in password
     pw_length = int(self.root.ids.input_entry)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 254, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__int__
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TextInput'
```

How to resolve?

Comment: Looks like you're passing in the field to `int()` rather than the value of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first the text field has to be limited to support only integers by adding the `input_filter: "int"`

```
TextInput:
    id: input_entry
    text: ''
    multiline: False
    font_family: 'Helvatica' 
    font_size: 24
    pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':4.5}
    size_hint: (2, .4)
    halign: "center"
    focus: True
    color: 'black'
    input_filter: "int"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing pw_length in your `password()` function to:

```
pw_length = int(self.root.ids.input_entry.text or 0)
```

input_entry is a TextInput which can't be converted to an int. I think you want to convert its value (`input_entry.text`) to an int, not the widget itself. To do that, change the `pw_length = ...` line in `password()` method as above.

Comment: Still an error :  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

When you use something like `self.root.ids.some_name` (or, `self.ids.some_name`) you are supposed to access a [weak reference](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets) of the named (`some_name`) widget from `root` (or, some class).

Now to get an attr. of that proxy widget you can go as usual using '.' syntax i.e. like `self.root.ids.some_name.prop` (or, `self.ids.some_name.prop`).

Here, `self.root.ids.output_entry` is a `TextInput` instance. So to access any of its properties you can do something like, `self.root.ids.output_entry.prop_name`. With this I modified `password` method as,

```py
    def password(self):
  
        self.root.ids.output_entry.text = ''
        
        input_text = self.root.ids.input_entry.text
        
        # Bellow you will handle user-input. You can use try-except or if-else or whatever that suits. I just implement a simple one.
        if input_text: # Means non-empty string.
            pw_length = int(input_text)
        else: # Raise Error or warn user via a message.
            pw_length = 0
            
       
        my_password = ''

        for x in range(pw_length):
            my_password += chr(randint(33, 126))

        self.root.ids.output_entry.text = my_password
```

Don't forget to apply the required changes (as described above) wherever necessary.